# Mac OS Sierra keeps crashing all of a sudden (panic)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

Not always, but usually when I try to wake my Macbook Pro up from screen saver it panics. I've tried to find what could be causing it, but I'm at a loss here.

Here's an EtreCheck log, hope it's of use.

```
    EtreCheck version: 3.4.6 (460)
Report generated 2017-11-07 12:35:23
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 1:51
Performance: Excellent

Click the [Lookup] links for more information from Apple Support Communities.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.
Click the [Remove/Report] links to remove adware or update the whitelist of legitimate software.

Problem: Computer is restarting
Description:
Damn thing keeps crashing.

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) 
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro13,2
    1 2,9 GHz Intel Core i5 (i5-6267U) CPU: 2-core
    8 GB RAM Not upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            4 GB LPDDR3 2133 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            4 GB LPDDR3 2133 MHz ok
    Handoff/Airdrop2: supported
    Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
    Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 18
    iCloud Quota: 4.89 GB available

Video Information: ⓘ
    Intel Iris Graphics 550 - VRAM: 1536 MB
        Color LCD 2880 x 1800
        DELL U2715H 2560 x 1440 @ 59 Hz
        DELL U2715H 2560 x 1440 @ 59 Hz

Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE SSD AP0256J disk0: (251 GB) (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)
        (disk0s1) <not mounted>  [EFI]: 315 MB
        (disk0s2) <not mounted>  [CoreStorage Container]: 250.04 GB
        Recovery HD (disk0s3 - Journaled HFS+) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 

USB Information: ⓘ
     USB30Bus 
        Apple, Inc. Keyboard Hub 
            Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard 
        Apple Inc. iBridge 
     USB31Bus 
     USB31Bus 

Thunderbolt Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus_1
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus_0

Virtual disks: ⓘ
    Macintosh HD (disk1 - Journaled HFS+) /  [Startup]: 249.68 GB (181.87 GB free)
        Encrypted AES-XTS (Unlocked)
        Physical disk: disk0s2 250.04 GB Online
    workspace (disk2s2 - Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+) /Users/jordyvandomselaar/workspace : 64.08 GB (52.08 GB free)
        Physical disk: Disk Image 64.08 GB (52.08 GB free)

System Software: ⓘ
    macOS Sierra  10.12.6 (16G29) - Time since boot: less than an hour

Configuration files: ⓘ
    /etc/hosts - Count: 87

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Possible adware: ⓘ
    Unknown file: /Library/LaunchAgents/ss_conn_service
    One possible adware file found. [Remove/Report]

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /Applications/Boom 2.app
    [loaded]    com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device (1.2 - SDK 10.10) [Lookup]

        /Library/Application Support/Samsung/SideSync/Samsung USB Driver/ssud_installation
    [not loaded]    com.devguru.driver.SamsungComposite (1.4.42 - SDK 10.6) [Lookup]

        /Library/Application Support/Samsung/SideSync/Samsung USB Driver/ssud_installation/ssuddrv.kext/Contents/PlugIns
    [not loaded]    com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMControl (1.4.42 - SDK 10.6) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData (1.4.42 - SDK 10.6) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    com.devguru.driver.SamsungMTP (1.4.42 - SDK 10.5) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    com.devguru.driver.SamsungSerial (1.4.42 - SDK 10.6) [Lookup]

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    7 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    174 Apple tasks
    [running]    101 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    40 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    159 Apple tasks
    [running]    117 Apple tasks

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    ss_conn_service (? 468ef167 ? - installed 2016-11-18) [Lookup]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [running]    com.devguru.ssconnservice.plist (? 51f4c13e 468ef167 - installed 2016-11-18) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.hidden.daemon.plist (? 2b76c037 18cdcc44 - installed 2017-11-07) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.workspace.plist (Apple, Inc. - installed 2017-08-02)
    [running]    de.appsolute.mampprohelper.plist (appsolute GmbH - installed 2017-08-02) [Lookup]

User Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2017-09-28) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.jetbrains.toolbox.plist (JetBrains s.r.o. - installed 2017-11-07) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.spotify.webhelper.plist (Spotify - installed 2017-11-07) [Lookup]

User Login Items: ⓘ
    Monosnap    Application - Hidden 
        (/Applications/Monosnap.app)
    MAMP PRO    Application - Hidden 
        (/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app)
    Spotify    Application - Hidden 
        (/Applications/Spotify.app)
    Backup and sync from Google    Application - Hidden 
        (/Applications/Backup and Sync.app)
    Dash    Application 
        (/Applications/Dash.app)
    Alfred 3    Application 
        (/Applications/Alfred 3.app)
    MonosnapLauncher    SMLoginItem - Hidden (Apple, Inc. - installed 2017-08-02)
        (/Applications/Monosnap.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/MonosnapLauncher.app)
    AirDroidHelper    SMLoginItem - Hidden (Jun Xiong - installed 2017-10-23)
        (/Applications/AirDroid.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/AirDroidHelper.app)
    CloudKitJS Callback URL    SMLoginItem - Hidden (AgileBits Inc. - installed 2017-08-28)
        (/Applications/1Password 6.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    QuickTime Plugin: 7.7.3 (installed 2017-08-02)

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    None

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Auto backup: YES
    Volumes being backed up:
        Macintosh HD: Disk size: 249.68 GB Disk used: 67.81 GB
    Destinations:
        TimeMachine [Network] 
        Total size: 804.96 GB 
        Total number of backups: 27 
        Oldest backup: 02/08/2017, 21:13 
        Last backup: 07/11/2017, 07:24 
        Size of backup disk: Excellent
            Backup size 804.96 GB > (Disk size 249.68 GB X 3)

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
         8%     WindowServer
         6%     Slack Helper
         4%     Slack
         3%     kernel_task
         2%     Spotify Helper

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    832 MB      kernel_task
    181 MB      Finder
    167 MB      phpstorm
    153 MB      Google Chrome
    151 MB      datagrip

Top Processes by Network Use: ⓘ
    Input       Output      Process name
    2 MB        22 KB       mDNSResponder
    1 MB        310 KB      Spotify
    932 KB      2 KB        AirDroid
    498 KB      3 KB        Sonos
    407 KB      2 KB        softwareupdated

Top Processes by Energy Use: ⓘ
     20.38  WindowServer
      6.58  phpstorm
      6.26  Slack Helper
      5.72  Google Chrome
      5.62  Backup and Sync

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    1.36 GB     Available RAM
    27 MB       Free RAM
    6.64 GB     Used RAM
    1.33 GB     Cached files
    211 MB      Swap Used

Software installs (last 30 days): ⓘ
    Boxy: 2.0.1 (installed 2017-11-06)

    Install information may not be complete.

Diagnostics Events (last 3 days for minor events): ⓘ
    2017-11-07 11:48:29    Kernel Panic [Open] [Details]
        3rd Party Kernel Extensions: 
                com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device    1.1
    2017-11-07 11:48:27    Last shutdown cause: 3 - Hard shutdown
    2017-11-06 08:25:03    Backup and Sync.app Crash [Open]
        Cause:        objc[685]: Invalid or prematurely-freed autorelease pool 0x1020ff8e8. Set a breakpoint on objc_autoreleasePoolInvalid to debug. Proceeding anyway because the app is old (SDK version 10.9.0). Memory errors are likely.
```

I've removed `Unknown file: /Library/LaunchAgents/ss_conn_service` apparently it was installed by Samsung.

Comment: First thing to do for any kernel panic is get rid of any non-Apple kexts... Boom should be the first to go, it's a known crasher.

Comment: @Tetsujin could you please tell me how to remove it? I'm a newby regarding macs.

Comment: That would really be a customer support issue. A simple Google search found this - http://www.globaldelight.com/support/discussion/1747/how-to-uninstall-boom-2

Comment: Yeah, I found it after a bit. I ran `sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device` -- Thanks anyways!

Comment: Seems like that fixed it. Mind adding your comment as an answer? That way I can accept it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do for any kernel panic is get rid of any non-Apple kexts...

Boom 2 should be the first to go, it's a known crasher.

It apparently has an uninstaller in the app itself, but failing that
`sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device`
ought to do it.

Thanks to the OP, [g3mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/223349/g3mini), for the kext unload command.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! It was driving me nuts hahahaha